# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith') - Mern Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at connectionStringHasValidScheme (D:\Development\Mern Stack\Backend\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:9:30)
    at new ConnectionString (D:\Development\Mern Stack\Backend\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:85:34)
```

It was all working before, but now when i tried to access some sample data from mongoDB Atlas, it showing me this error

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling the `startsWith` function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue a couple of minutes ago connecting to mongodb from js driver. So I was following along a tutorial and the steps they said were for the old driver for the new one the correct code is here.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
// CRUD

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'task-manager'
const MongoClient = new mongodb.MongoClient(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true })


MongoClient.connect((error, client) => {
    if(error){
        return console.log('Unable to connect to database')
    }
    console.log(`Connected correctly`)
});
```

Comment: this is hanging for me - nothing in the `MongoClient.connect` callback is getting called. i'm using mongodb version 6.0 if it matters

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I didn't passed the dbconnection url while creating the client. I missed `config.mongoDb.dbUrl`.

info: value of `config.mongodb.dburl` is  `"dbUrl": "mongodb+srv://kushal-seth:<<password>>@project.cccccccc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const config = require("../config.json");

const client = new MongoClient(config.mongoDb.dbUrl);
await client.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your:

```js
const MongoClient = new mongodb.MongoClient(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Inside some function. The `.env` file takes some time to initialize.

Or:

Move your `.env` file into src directory in which u are working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the mongodb connection URL is in the **.env** file

This article helped me: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/typeerror-cannot-read-property-startswith-of-undefined/146999/6

Comment: Please add an example of how this part of the `.env` file should look like

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link that attempts to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this working:

```
const Client = new MongoClient(URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

So I updated `mongodb` and started receiving the following warning:

```
[MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: 
useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 
and will be removed in the next major version (Use `node --trace-warnings 
...` to show where the warning was created)
```

So I removed the option:

```
const Client = new MongoClient(URL)
```

But now I started receiving the OP error. So adding an empty option solved for me:

```
const Client = new MongoClient(URL, {})
```