# Node server.js Mern stack tutorial question

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial) step by step on Windows 10, and when I get to the section where I run `Node server.js` I get the error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\mern\server\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:9
    return (connectionString.startsWith('mongodb://') ||



TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at connectionStringHasValidScheme (C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\mern\server\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js:9:30)
```

and there are more `at` items after this. I do not get the expected

```
Server is running on port: 5000
Successfully connected to MongoDB.
```

It looks like this exact question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435139/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-startswith-mern-sta) but wasn't answered.

When I run `node --version` I get `v18.12.1` and `java --version` produces `java 19.0.1 2022-10-18`.

When I inspect the `index.js` file with the function, it defines the function as

```
function connectionStringHasValidScheme(connectionString) {
    return (connectionString.startsWith('mongodb://') ||
        connectionString.startsWith('mongodb+srv://'));
}
```

I am new to MERN stack, hence the tutorial. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Show how you call `connectionStringHasValidScheme`

Comment: I am honestly not sure, as the `index.js` file that contains `connectionStringHasValidScheme` is created with the command `npm install mongodb express cors dotenv` along with other modules. The location is `mern\server\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\lib\index.js`

Comment: Oh ok. Show how you connect to mongodb then

Comment: Yes so I create a file called `config.env` at the location `mern\server\config.env` and write `mongodb+srv://myusername:<mypassword>@cluster0.q0uxshf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority \n PORT=5000`. Then I create a new file called `conn.js` at the location `mern\server\db\conn.js`, and it's too long to type here but can be found under **Connecting to MongoDB Atlas** in the [tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial)

Comment: The problem is that your connection string is wrong